# In the First Jewish-Roman War (The Great Revolt of 66-73AD, aka "the Great Tribulation") what percentage of Jews died?

Tags: history, zechariah, great-revolt

> According to [Josephus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus), [1.1 million non-combatants died in Jerusalem](https://pace.webhosting.rug.nl/york/york/showText?book=6&chapter=9&textChunk=whistonSection&chunkId=3&up.x=&up.y=&text=wars&version=&direction=&tab=&layout=english) and 100,000 in Galilee. He also tells us that 97,000 were enslaved.
>
> Matthew White estimates the combined death toll[clarification needed] for the First and Third Roman Jewish Wars [as being approximately 350,000](http://Matthew%20White,%20The%20Great%20Big%20Book%20of%20Horrible%20Things%20(Norton,%202012)%20p.52).

Zechariah says that 2/3 of the Jews would die:

> [Zec 13:7-9 KJV] 7 Awake, O sword, against my shepherd, and against the man [that is] my fellow, saith the LORD of hosts: smite the shepherd, and the sheep shall be scattered: and I will turn mine hand upon the little ones. 8 And it shall come to pass, [that] in all the land, saith the LORD, **two parts therein shall be cut off [and] die**; but the third shall be left therein. 9 And I will bring the third part through the fire, and will refine them as silver is refined, and will try them as gold is tried: they shall call on my name, and I will hear them: I will say, It [is] my people: and they shall say, The LORD [is] my God.

[image: The Arch of Titus]

This is in keeping with the predictions of various prophecies:

> [Eze 9:4 KJV] 4 And the LORD said unto him, Go through the midst of the city, through the midst of Jerusalem, and set a mark upon the foreheads of the men that sigh and that cry for all the abominations that be done in the midst thereof.
>
> [Rev 7:3 KJV] 3 Saying, Hurt not the earth, neither the sea, nor the trees, till we have sealed the servants of our God in their foreheads.
>
> [Rev 7:4 KJV] 4 And I heard the number of them which were sealed: [and there were] sealed an hundred [and] forty [and] four thousand of all the tribes of the children of Israel.
>
> [Rev 9:4 KJV] 4 And it was commanded them that they should not hurt the grass of the earth, neither any green thing, neither any tree; but only those men which have not the seal of God in their foreheads.
>
> [Rev 14:1 KJV] 1 And I looked, and, lo, a Lamb stood on the mount Sion, and with him an hundred forty [and] four thousand, having his Father's name written in their foreheads.
>
> [Rev 22:4 KJV] 4 And they shall see his face; and his name [shall be] in their foreheads.

I realize that 144,000 is probably symbolic but I'm wondering about the percentage of 2/3 that were to perish in relation to the extant numbers.

How many actually died in that war and how does that relate to Zechariah's prediction of 2/3?

Comment: Good question. But wouldn't this be served better at History:SE?

Comment: @LangLangC I appreciate the suggestion. If I strike out here I'll post a similar question on that site.

Comment: Well, I know not enough on how this site *really* works; can't even see close votes. But I think, without checking over there for dupes, that an edit here and a shifted Q there would be most interesting. I do not favour deleting such an interesting Q. Currently it looks to me as sitting between both site's focus. If it flies here, well then.